# \hbox spread in plain TeX

Tags: spacing, boxes, plain-tex

I want to learn Plain TeX to understand the underlying mechanics of TeX and friends. I am trying to reproduce the spacing of this dedication from the Spanish music-theory treatise, *El porque de la música*, by Andrés Lorente (Alcalá, 1672).

[image]

Here is the best I can do so far:

[image]

**Why does the `\hbox spread \hsize` command create an `\hbox` larger than the `\hsize`?**

(Also, why is the spacing so uneven between lines?)

```
\hoffset=0.5in
\hsize=5.5in

\font\Huge=cmr10 at 48pt
\font\Large=cmr10 at 36pt
\font\large=cmr10 at 24pt
\font\big=cmr10 at 16pt
\font\mainfont=cmr10 at 12pt
\mainfont

\def\spreadtitleline #1 {\hbox spread \hsize\bgroup#1\egroup \titlelineskip}
\def\centertitleline #1 {\line{\hss #1\hss}\titlelineskip}
\def\titlelineskip {\par\vskip 1ex}

%****************************************

\spreadtitleline{\Huge A MARIA SAN-}
\spreadtitleline{\Large TISSIMA, NVESTRA}
\spreadtitleline{\large ABOGADA, Y SE\~NORA, CONCE-}
{\big
\centertitleline{bida sin mancha de Pecado Original, en el}
\centertitleline{Primer Instante de}
\centertitleline{su Ser.}
}

\bye
```

Comment: The spacing is uneven as you have not increased `\baselineskip` so you are setting large text on a small baseline, so TeX can not achieve even spacing

Comment: Thanks. I will look into defining a font-size command that also changes the `baselineskip`. For this example, perhaps I also need looser inter-character spacing by changing `glue` settings.

Comment: Or just use latex, where size changing commands are set up to change the baseline already:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`spread` is that much *extra* width, you want `to` which specifies the final width

Answer (score 8):

Here's some additional ideas for you for use with XeTeX:

```
\uselanguage{spanish}

\def\mainfont{EB Garamond}
\font\hugefn="\mainfont:letterspace=10" at 30bp
\font\largefn="\mainfont:letterspace=5" at 22bp
\font\bigfn="\mainfont:letterspace=5" at 14bp % NOTE: \big is already defined!
\font\mainfn="\mainfont:+hlig;+onum" at 12bp % historical ligatures, old style numbers
\mainfn

\def\gaps{\spaceskip=.3333em plus 1fil }

\hsize=19pc
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil \rightskip=\leftskip \parfillskip=0pt \obeylines
\openup2\jot \line{\hugefn\gaps A MARIA SAN\rlap{-}}
\line{\largefn\gaps TISSIMA \raise.5ex\hbox{,} NVESTRA}
\line{\bigfn\gaps ABOGADA , Y SEÑORA , CONCE-}
\openup-1\jot bida ſin mancha de Pecado Original, en el
Primer Inſtante de
ſu Ser.
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! I will study it! I also want to see if it works with `fbb` or Cardo fonts.

Comment: How did you adjust the baselineskips?

Comment: @Andrew: With the `\openup`, which `\advance`s all of `\lineskip`, `\baselineskip`, and `\lineskiplimit` by the amount of its dimen argument. The amount `\jot` is defined by default to be 3pt.